# How do I change the size of a rectangle while painting a histogram?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, paint

Actually I am new to java gui, and here I want to change the rectangle height whenever we put something in text field and press button, but I don't know how to do it, actually I checked in a ton of sited but I couldn't find an easy way.Actually I can't find how to change rectangle size that is inside paintComponent inside the MyPanel class.

(The logic for height change is how many vowels capital and small,and consonents and other things are there in string)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Hist{
    int h1=0,h2=0,h3=0,h4=0,h5=0;
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    JButton b=new JButton("click");
    JTextField text=new JTextField(30);


public static void main(String args[]){
    Hist h=new Hist();

}

Hist(){

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.add(new MyPanel(h1,h2,h3,h4,h5));
    f.setSize(400,300);
    f.setVisible(true);

    f.add(b);
    f.add(text);

    thehandler handler=new thehandler();
    b.addActionListener(handler);

}
class thehandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if(event.getSource()==b){
            h1=0;h2=0;h3=0;h4=0;h5=0;
            String s;
            s=text.getText();
            char[] ar=s.toCharArray();
            for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
                if(ar[i]=='a'||ar[i]=='e'||ar[i]=='i'||ar[i]=='o'||ar[i]=='u'){
                    h1=h1+10;
                }
                else if(ar[i]=='A'||ar[i]=='E'||ar[i]=='I'||ar[i]=='O'||ar[i]=='U'){
                    h2=h2+10;
                }
                else{
                    h5=h5+10;
                }
            }

        }
    }

 }
}


class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    int x1,x2,x3,x4,x5;
    public MyPanel(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e){
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        x1=a;x2=b;x3=c;x4=d;x5=e;
    }
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(350,200);
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponents(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(25, 25, 30,x1);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(75, 25, 30, x2);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(125, 25, 30,x3);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(175, 25, 30, x4);

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(225, 25, 30, x5);

    }
}
```

Comment: On `ActionEvent` get/set the new value and call `repaint()`.

Comment: Do the `h1`, `h2`.. somehow relate to the `x1`, `x2`.. attributes?  I find you variable names confusing, since the way they are used the `x` attributes are used is as a `height` that I'd prefix with `h`!

Answer (score 5):

> *"Actually I can't find how to change rectangle size that is inside paintComponent"*

It looks like the way you're doing it will only change the height and not the `y` location. Which would be fine if it were an upside down histogram.

What you need to do is have a starting point for y, say 400 for a screen with height 450, so the horizon is near the bottom

```
int y = 400;
```

So when you draw it will be

```
g.fillRect(25, y - height, 30, height)
```

Now height will be the y starting point, 400. And when you want to increase it, you actually need to decrease 400.

So if you want the height to be 150, then you need to -150

```
g.fillRect(25, y - 150, 30, height);
```

This will give the effect a bar rising from the horizon line

For every `g.fillRect` you should calculate a new height, so you can have a `height` varaible. and a `final INCREMENT` variable based on how many vowels. So something like this

```
final int INCREMENT = 25;
int height;

....

height = numberOfAs * INCREMENT;
g.fillRect(25, y - height, 30, height);
height = numberOfEs * INCREMENT;
g.fillRect(75, y - height, 30, height);
height = numberOfOs * INCREMENT;
g.fillRect(125, y - height, 30, height);
height = numberOfIs * INCREMENT;
g.fillRect(175, y - height, 30, height);
height = numberOfUs * INCREMENT;
g.fillRect(225, y - height, 30, height);
```

---

Run this example to see what I'm talking about

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Histogram extends JPanel {

    private static final int DIM_WIDTH = 300;
    private static final int DIM_HEIGHT = 450;

    int height;
    private static final int INCREMENT = 50;
    int numberOfAs = 4;
    int numberOfEs = 2;
    int numberOfIs = 1;
    int numberOfOs = 5;
    int numberOfUs = 6;
    int y = 400;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        height = numberOfAs * INCREMENT;
        g.fillRect(25, y - height, 30, height);
        height = numberOfEs * INCREMENT;
        g.fillRect(75, y - height, 30, height);
        height = numberOfOs * INCREMENT;
        g.fillRect(125, y - height, 30, height);
        height = numberOfIs * INCREMENT;
        g.fillRect(175, y - height, 30, height);
        height = numberOfUs * INCREMENT;
        g.fillRect(225, y - height, 30, height);
    }

    public static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new Histogram());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(DIM_WIDTH, DIM_HEIGHT);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

From left to right with an `INCREMENT` of 50 pixels per letter

```
As = 4;
Es = 2;
Os = 5;
Is = 1;
Us = 6;
```

---

**Also** in a program where you want to be able to control the the repaint with a text field entry, you can have `setters` in your `MyPanel` class that will set the values of the `numberOfXs` variables. After you get them from whatever method you use to get them, just call `setNumberOfAs(int numberOfAs)` and the rest of the setters, and call repaint. So for each time an input is taken from the textField, and you have updated the variabels in `MyPanel`, the painted histogram should update.

---

**UPDATE**

Another way you can do it is to make both the `ActionListener` *and* the `MyPanel` *inner classes* of `Hist`. That way can they can share the global variables of `Hist`. Make the `NumberOfXs` variable members of the `Hist` class so all inner classes can share. In the `ActionListener` class in your `actionPerformed`, change the variables accordingly and `repaint` the `MyPanel`. If you did it this way, you wouldn't need to pass an parameters to the constructor of `MyPanel`

---

**UPDATE 2**

I don't want to do your complete assignment for you, so I'll give you a basic outline.

- Make both class inner classes of `Hist`
- Have the `numberOfXs` variables class members of `Hist`, not in `MyPanel`
- Create an instance of `MyPanel` in `Hist` as a class member so it can be accesed by the `ActionListener`
- Get the values for the `numberOfXs` in your `actionPerformed` then call repaint

Something like this

```
public class Hist {
    MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
    int numberOfAs;
    int numberOfEs;
    int numberOfIs;
    int numberOfOs;
    int numberOfUs;

    private class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        // do your painting
    }

    private class MyListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            // get the values for numberOfXs however you do it. Make sure to numberOfXs = someValue
            myPanel.repaint();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,that's what I wanted,but now I want to add a button with a text field to take input and change the values of As ,Es and also change the histogram respectively.

Comment: Sorry brother,to ask you again,but this is my first program of repaint, and I am not able to do it, can you please modify your code and show me the repaint.

Comment: Wow!  I looked at the code briefly and realized it had so many problems I did not have time to get into it.  Your effort is superb.  And an excellent screenshot just to make it all the better.  Marvelous.. :)

Answer (score 2):

In your MyPanel define a method(s) to pass values and set them to the x1 - x5 fields.

e.g.

```
public void setValues(int a,int b,int c,int d,int e){
    x1=a;x2=b;x3=c;x4=d;x5=e;
}
```

When something chnages just call the setValues() with proper calculated values.